# Applying the forwarding fillna() in Pandas with reseting based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I need to do forward fillna() on a Pandas dataframe in a specifict manner. Let me explain it.

I have a dataframe with 3 columns city, age, medicine (sorted by ['city', 'Age']).

|  | city | Age | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NY | 30 | Nan |
| 1 | NY | 35 | 12AA |
| 2 | NY | 40 | Nan |
| 3 | NY | 45 | Nan |
| 4 | NY | 50 | 15AA |
| 5 | NY | 55 | Nan |
| 6 | LA | 25 | Nan |
| 7 | LA | 30 | Nan |
| 8 | LA | 35 | 14DD |
| 9 | LA | 40 | Nan |
| 10 | LA | 45 | 12AA |
| 11 | LA | 50 | Nan |
| 12 | LA | 55 | Nan |
| 13 | DC | 35 | Nan |

What I need to do is to fill Nan values in the forwarding direction (replace the Nan values by the previous non-Nan value). The only twist is that when the city changes the forwarding fillna should be reset. The following table shows the desired output.

|  | city | Age | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | NY | 30 | Nan |
| 1 | NY | 35 | 12AA |
| 2 | NY | 40 | 12AA |
| 3 | NY | 45 | 12AA |
| 4 | NY | 50 | 15AA |
| 5 | NY | 55 | 15AA |
| 6 | LA | 25 | Nan |
| 7 | LA | 30 | Nan |
| 8 | LA | 35 | 14DD |
| 9 | LA | 40 | 14DD |
| 10 | LA | 45 | 12AA |
| 11 | LA | 50 | 12AA |
| 12 | LA | 55 | 12AA |
| 13 | DC | 35 | Nan |

How can I do this kind of forwarding fillna in pandas that reset based on the city column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try [groupby ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-ffill):

```py
df['Value'] = df.groupby('city')['Value'].ffill()
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   city  Age Value
0    NY   30   NaN
1    NY   35  12AA
2    NY   40  12AA
3    NY   45  12AA
4    NY   50  15AA
5    NY   55  15AA
6    LA   25   NaN
7    LA   30   NaN
8    LA   35  14DD
9    LA   40  14DD
10   LA   45  12AA
11   LA   50  12AA
12   LA   55  12AA
13   DC   35   NaN
```